# Write string into ini file with gulp-ini : bad encoding value

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

I use the following gulp task to update an ini file :

```
gulp.task('prepareDelivery', ['copy'], function () {
    var config = ini.parse(fs.readFileSync(destination + '/ini/app_sample.ini', 'utf-8'));
    config.DATA.version = "\"" +res.version + "\"";
    fs.writeFileSync(destination + '/ini/app.ini', ini.stringify(config));
});
```

When i execute the task, i get this output:

```
[DATA]
version="\"1.0\""
```

I would like to get :

```
[DATA]
version="1.0"
```

Where is the problem ?

Comment: Did you try `config.DATA.version = res.version;`?

Comment: @AmiramKorach Yes, it print : `version=1.0` and i want to have `version="1.0"`

Comment: What about `1.0.toFixed(1)'?